# Exception on camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

New to Android programming here.

I have had a look around and have found this to be a common issue, but I don't really see an easy fix... I am trying to run the following code on a Nexus 7 (have tried AVD & physical device) with no luck whatsoever. It seems to be the:

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder);
```

But I could be wrong. Here is the current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

 Camera camera;
 SurfaceView surfaceView;
 SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 boolean previewing = false;;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.cameralayout);


       getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
       surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
       surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
       surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

   }

   public void onClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!previewing){
     camera = Camera.open();
     if (camera != null){
      try {
       camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
       camera.startPreview();
       previewing = true;
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
    }
   }
```

Any ideas folks? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you post your `SurfaceHolder.Callback` implementation?

Comment: It's not crashing anymore but I put a toast inside a try/catch to show the error and I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException. Don't know if that helps... Cheers!

Comment: @system32 this is basically the entire code. I got it from another source. Thanks.

Comment: You can post that solution and mark your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29) about `Camera.open()`

> Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on
>   the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this
>   returns null.

It gives you only an access to back-facing Camera.

> I am trying to run the following code on a Nexus 7

`Camera.open()` returns `null` because Nexus 7 doesn't have a back camera, only a front camera.

You could try this method

```
public Camera getCamera()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++)
        return Camera.open(i);

    return null;
}
```

To apply,

```
camera = getCamera();
```

Comment: I can't believe that's all it was. Thank you very much - works fantastic!